# Disable Anti-Aliasing Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, cross-browser

I've got some problems with Safari and OpenSans. The font really seems rasterized. After some researches, I've find out that part of the problem could be resolved with:

```
* {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
```

But it's not enough as you can see in the screenshot below. I've tried to apply some text-shadow and even -webkit-text-stroke, but the results is deteriorated on other browsers.

[image: Chrome ScreenShot][image: Safari ScreenShot]

The result in real: https://waaave.com/tutorial/php/playing-with-the-instagram-api-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

This css should work:

```
img { 
  image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;             /* GIVE ME SPEED                  */
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;          /* Firefox                        */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;            /* Opera                          */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Chrome (and eventually Safari) */
  image-rendering: optimize-contrast;         /* CSS3 Proposed                  */
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;   /* IE8+                           */
}
```

[source](http://nullsleep.tumblr.com/post/16417178705/how-to-disable-image-smoothing-in-modern-web-browsers)

Comment: Thank's, but I'm not talking about the images but the text.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the backface visibility. Try this:

```
* {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
}
```

Backfacing is meant for animations in browsers. Essentially it is rendering the element twice. Think of it as being in a 3D space. If you turn the font around, you should still see it. Backface visibility is essentially rendering the font on the opposing side of the viewport incase you want to rotate it. Thankfully you can disable this attribute if you don't need it.

Comment: There seems to be a little improvement on Firefox, but the result is still bad on Safari.